# Why does adding a ArrayList to a jsonObject using the accumulate method not deliver a JSONArray

Tags: java, json, arraylist, org.json

I have the following method which adds an ArrayList as a JSON Array to an JSON structure and adds a new value to the JSONArray.

```
private void test() {

    ArrayList<String> myCollection = new ArrayList<String>()
            {{
              add("a") ;
              add("b") ;
              add("c") ;
          }} ;

     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject() ;

     try {
        jsonObject.put("FirstKey", "Hi Mum!") ;
        jsonObject.accumulate("MyKey", myCollection) ;
        System.out.println("JSON Structure " + jsonObject.toString()) ;
        jsonObject.append("MyKey", "x") ;
        System.out.println("JSON Structure " + jsonObject.toString()) ;
     } catch (JSONException jex) {
         System.out.println("Exception: "  + jex.getMessage() ) ;
     }         
}
```

When executed the following output is produced.

```
JSON Structure {"MyKey":["a","b","c"],"FirstKey":"Hi Mum!"}
Exception: JSONObject[MyKey] is not a JSONArray.
```

As far as i can see the value for "MyKey" is a valid JSONarray. Only when appending a single value the exception is thrown that the value for "MyKey" is not a JSON Array.

According to the [org.json.JSONObject documentation](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html) the append method adds the value to an existing JSONArray.

If myCollection is converted to a JSONArray first

```
this.jsonObject.accumulate(key, new JSONArray(value)) ;
```

Then the existing collection is converted to a JSONArray, wrapped in a second array. And the additional value is added into to wrapped array.

```
>2>>>>{"key1":"hashmaptest","keycoll":[["a","b","c"]]}
>3>>>>{"key1":"hashmaptest","keycoll":[["a","b","c"],"x"]}
```

After replacing the accumulate method by a put method without converting the arraylist to a JSONArray, the ArrayList is also added as a JSONArray. And the additional value is added to the JSONArray as expected.

```
>1>>>>{"key1":"hashmaptest"}
>2>>>>{"key1":"hashmaptest","keycoll":["a","b","c"]}
>3>>>>{"key1":"hashmaptest","keycoll":["a","b","c","x"]}
```

How can i create a JSONArray from a HashMap or add a HashMap or single values to a JSONArray correctly? (Or is this a bug in org.json ?)

-- update 1 --

I now have fixed it by iterating over the collection, but am not sure if this is the best solution.

```
 /**
 * Adds or updates a JSON object to the JSON structure. If an Object with
 * the specified key exists it is updated with the new values. Value needs
 * to be a single value of type boolean,int,long,double,Boolean,
 * Integer,Long, String or a Collection of any of these types.
 *
 *
 * @param key Unique key
 * @param value An object of the following types; boolean,
 * @return JsonLogger
 */
public JsonLogger collection(String key, Object value) {

    try {
        if (SINGLE_VALUE_TYPES.contains(value.getClass())) {
            this.jsonObject.accumulate(key, value);
        }

        if (value instanceof java.util.Collection) {
            Iterator i = ((java.util.Collection) value).iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                this.jsonObject.accumulate(key, i.next());
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        this.internalLogger(Level.ERROR, ex.getMessage());
    }

    return this;
}
```